# Configuring Ejabberd on ubuntu ami of amazon ec2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, xmpp, ejabberd

I have installed [Ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im/) server on ubuntu 12.04 AMI on Amazon EC2.

I have successfully installed the server, added the admin user and host in the config file and opened up reqd ports (5222, 5223, 5269, 5280).

I successfully loged the web admin interface using the Admin user-id and password.

BUT after logging-in I could only see one section, Virtual Hosts as shown in the below image

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

**My Problem**
I could not see any Control Lists, Access rules, Nodes and Statistics Menu items on the left.

Also, when I click Virtual Hosts Menu item, the page that comes up does not show anything.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have modified authentication mechanism to some thing other than "internal".

If yes, then you have to configure virtual hosts in the external database being used.